# How to improve HBase Scanner?

Tags: hbase

Ho do I configure HBase so that the scanner only retrieves a number of records at a time? Or how do I improve the scanner when the database contains a lot of records/

Answer (score 11):

I believe the scanner only actually requests one item at a time unless you set the caching. You can check just to be sure with getCaching()

Each time you call ResultScanner#next(), it will retrieve the next item. You can also use ResultScanner#next(int) to retrieve a number of results at a time.

When setting up the scanner you can use Scan#setCaching to retrieve results in advance
http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase/docs/r0.20.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setCaching(int)

The chances are your scanner is slow because you are only reading one record at a time(that includes all of the back and forth of the RPC protocol and whatnot). So if you intend to read a lot, let the system cache a few results for you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to examine the Filter API, which allows you to selectively return a subset of rows or cells to the client: http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/package-summary.html.

Comment: the following URL is also helpful for filters: http://hbase.apache.org/book/client.filter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scan.setMaxResultSize` to control the records retrieved from `HBase` every time. (It does not mean then you get less results from this query)

If you want to limit the result like SQL `select top 100 from TABLE;`
You need to use a `PageFilter` ^_^